# Let $V=\Bbb{R}^2$ and $S$ is the set of all vectors $(x,y)$ in $V$ satisfying $3x+2y=0$. Is it a subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

the set is $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid 3x+2y=0\}$ Is it right I have no idea how to determine it is a subspace $(0,0)$ is a zero vector and it is in $S$ what about inverse.I see it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition then how should I prove? can anyone give a detailed solution and set notation form.

Comment: In order for a subset of a vector space to be a subspace, all you need to check if it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, which is a simple exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You already checked it is not empty as the zero vector is in it, so now you *must* check that

1) Whenever $\;(a,b),\,(c,d)\in S\;$ , also $\;(a,b)+(c,d)\in S\;$ , and also

2) Whenever $\;(a,b)\in S\;$ and for **any** $\;k\in\Bbb R\;$,  also $\;k(a,b)\in S\;$ .

Both things are very easy to verify in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

You  can simply note that from the definition of $S$ you have:
$$
3x+2y=0 \quad \iff \quad y=-\frac{3}{2}x
$$

si the vectors in $S$ have the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\-\frac{3}{2}x
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can you do from this?